# How do I find $P(A), P(B), P(C)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Would someone help to solve and explain this problem?

Total exported devices $2425000$ per year. The top exported device:
Device A ($725790$), device B ($537390$), and device C ($159877$).

1. Calculate $P(A), P(B)$, and $P(C)$.
2. Are the events $A$ and $B$ mutually exclusive?  Why? and compute $P(A ∩B)$.
3. Find the probability exported device from $A$ or $C$?
4. What is the probability to export other than one of these three?

Here is my solution, would check it please:

**Q1/**

$P(A)=725790/(725790+537390+159877)=0.51002173$

$P(B)=537390/(725790+537390+159877)=0.37763069$

$P(C)=159877/(725790+537390+159877)=0.11234757$

**Q2**

Yes, they are mutually exclusive, that the same device cannot be exported twice, therefore;  $P(A∩C)=0$.

**Q3**

$P(A∪C)=P(A)+ P(C)= 0.51002173+ 0.37763069= 0.88765242$

**Q4**

$(2425000-1423057)/425000= 0.4132$

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo :)

Comment: Seems context has been provided as suggested by @Shaun. There are errors, but additional voters on 'closure' should review the question as _currently_ posed.

Comment: "Calculate $P(A)$" is meaningless until an event named $A$ has been defined. The problem statement does not define any event named $A$; it says only that there is a type of device designated Device A and that 725790 copies of that device are exported. We may be expected to make a leap of faith to conclude that the question is about a single device selected at random from all the imports during the year, and $A$ is the event that the selected device is of type A. I would make any such assumptions _very_ explicit in any answer I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing your work. Here are some Comments.

You are partly on the right track, but in
(1)  denominators should be 2425000. The way you have it $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$
and that contradicts what you have in (4), which may be OK.

You may be right about (2), but not for the reason given. If $A$ and $C$
are exported independently, then $P(A \cap C) = P(A)P(C).$ If they
are mutually exclusive then $P(A \cap C) = 0.$ I hope there is more
information about this than you have given. If not, you need to make and
state assumptions.

Then in (3) you have  $P(A \cup C) = P(A)+P(C)-P(A\cap C).$ In addition to
the uncertainty about $P(A \cap C)$, you have
the wrong values of $P(A)$ and $P(C)$ from (1).

Answer (score 1):

1.

$P(A)= \frac{725790}{2425000}=0.299294845$

$P(B)= \frac{537390}{2425000}=0.221604124$

$P(C)= \frac{159877}{2425000}=0.06592866$

2.

If two events are mutually exclusive then $P(Event_1) ∩ P(Event_2) = 0 $. And

> Yes, they are mutually exclusive, that the same device cannot be exported twice, therefore; P(A∩C)=0.

is wrong statement. Firstly, Device A and Device B are not same devices. In this context "mutually exclusive" means Devices A and B cannot be exported at the same time. Which means they are dependent.

3.

Answer is wrong if two events are independent.

4.

(Total minus sum of A, B and C) divided by Total.

Comment: Good point about independence or disjointness of $A$ and $C.$ (+1) Seems unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. About Q2, yes you right, then $P(A∩C)=P(A)P(C)$.
ABout Q3, would please explain more.

Comment: Sorry, but do you mean with "Total minus sum of A, B and C) divided by Total." ?

is it :
$(2425000 - (A+B+C)) / 2425000$